# I love this puzzle to the moon and back!

Tags: number-sequence

407 8208 4151

What is the next number????

Hint:

> It can have more than 1 answer!

Comment: Is there something specific that would narrow down the result to a single answer?

Comment: Does the pattern continues infinitely? If yes, would you mind giving more numbers? If no, when does it end?

Comment: Just a note about your hint. Having multiple possible answers is usually not a very well accepted thing here.

Comment: It's likely the OP meant, that THOUGH this has more than 1 answer, there is still The One answer he expects, likely characterized by the following: linked to the moon (like 1969, or 11) and simple (simpler than a second power polynomial)

Comment: I've reopened this question because it has become clear that there is a fairly clear "right" answer. See the discussion that was originally on a now-deleted answer but was [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61711/discussion-on-answer-by-edderiofer-i-love-this-puzzle-to-the-moon-and-back).

Comment: @starkgurl I suggest that you should probably post a solution, since you were the first person to see what is going on in this puzzle.

Answer (score 7):

> **548834**

> An Armstrong number (moon and back) is a number whose individual integers to a common power of n add up to that number.
>  $407 = n^3 =  4^3 + 0^3 + 7^3 = 64 + 0 + 343$ 
>  $8208$ is an $n^4 = 8^4 + 2^4 + 0^4 + 8^4 = 4096 + 16 + 0 + 4096 = 8208$ 
>  
>  $4151$ is an $n^5 = 4^5 + 1^5 + 5^5 + 1^5 = 1024 + 1 + 3125 +1 = 4151$ 
>  
>  $548834$ is $n^6$, and the only one less than 2147483647 (max size of an integer) $= 5^6 + 4^6 + 8^6 + 8^6 + 3^6 + 4^6 =  15625 + 4096 + 262144 + 262144 + 729 + 4096 = 548834$

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange. I see what you mean and why this is probably the correct solution. However, you should explain it in a little more detail because it's still not 'obvious'.

Comment: added explanation and math to clarify the answer

Comment: 4151 is not a real Armstrong number even if 4^5+1^5+5^5+1^5=4151 it should be 4^4+1^4+5^4+1^4 which is 883 different from 4151 (number of digits 4 not 5)

Comment: Armstrong numbers are those numbers which are equal to the sum of the digits of the number each raised to the power of the number of digits in the number itself